# USBasp problem: could not upload sketches to Arduino clone with PL2303 USB-to-UART chip

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, avrdude

I'm trying to upload sketch to a Gizduino board (these boards have PL2303 chip for USB-to-Serial communication; other than that they are entirely similar with Arduino Uno).

I have installed the driver for it and can verify that the board associates to a COM Port whenever the board is connected to my PC (Win10) via USB. But everytime I try to upload a sketch, IDE (tried with 1.8.2 and 1.6.9) throws the error below, with or without the PL2303 driver installed on my PC.

```
avrdude: error: could not find USB device with vid=0x16c0 pid=0x5dc vendor='www.fischl.de' product='USBasp'
```

I'm certain that I have selected the right board from the Boards List.

So my intuition was that the PL2303 driver is not working the way it should be. I've been trying to get more information about avrdude and USBasp but so far was not able to find anything remotely similar to my case.

**UPDATE:** Realized that all I needed to do is install the driver for USBasp (whihch I'm having trouble doing); this post could be off-topic. But I'm urged to raise another question: Which programmer should I select from the programmer list? Currently its "AVRISP mkII". In fact it doesn't matter which one I use. Same error about USBasp occurs with any of them selected.

Comment: You told the IDE to upload through an USBASP, but apparently you are no using an USBASP, so avrdude complains it cannot find it.

Comment: Hi. I updated the post.

Comment: Really frustrating. Tried on 3 different pc's. same board. same problem. Found nothing related in the internet. Not even in stackexchange is there somebody who got any idea about this seemingly ubiquitous issue. at this point I'll just take it that my board is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a USBasp plugged into the computer? if yes then you need to install USBasp driver else why don't you just use the bootloader option from the arduino IDE.